# How do I get JSX supported in my application?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have the following in my `index.js` file

```
class PersonProfileBadge extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.alias = this.props.alias;
    }

    render() {
        return e(
            'img',
            {
                src: `https://internal-cdn.foo.com/somepath/?uid=${this.alias}`,
                className: 'profile_photo'
            }
        );
    }
}
```

and it works when I render it like so

```
ReactDOM.render(
    e(PersonProfileBadge, {'alias': 'stupidfatcat'}),
    navProfilePicture
);
```

But I'm trying to get JSX support since it makes the code look generally much more readable

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <PersonProfileBadge alias='stupidfatcat' />,
  navProfilePicture
);
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

In my index.html I have the following imports

```
<script src="internalcdnpathto/static/react/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="internalcdnpathto/static/react-dom/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/index.js"></script>
```

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong or where to even get started.

Comment: Does `<script type="text/babel" src="/static/index.js">` works? Also check in Network Tab of Dev Tools in your browser that the .js files gets loaded without any error

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html - Read the bottom of that website on how to have the Babel preprocessor run in real time to convert your jsx code into vanilla js.  That's how I learned how to do the same thing you are trying to do.  The only thing I did differently was have the command line parameters operate on different directories.

Comment: Aha that did work @ShriHari that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally want to [add a preprocessor](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) in order to use JSX. The quickest way to try JSX in your project is to add this  tag to your page:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can use JSX in any  tag by adding type="text/babel" attribute to it. This approach is fine for learning and creating simple demos. However, it makes your website slow and isn’t suitable for production.

Read more [in the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#run-jsx-preprocessor).

Answer (score 0):

You need babel to compile your code from JSX to javascript from this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <PersonProfileBadge alias='stupidfatcat' />,
  navProfilePicture
);
```

to that:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  e(PersonProfileBadge, {'alias': 'stupidfatcat'}),
  navProfilePicture
);
```

You should utilize a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) so you parse your code everytime you change something, i'd suggest creating a project via `create-react-app`

or take a look at [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone)